# Django1.1 model field value preprocessing before returning

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model class like this:

```
class Note(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='notes')
    content = NoteContentField(max_length=256)
```

**NoteContentField** is a custom sub-class of **CharField** that override the **to_python** method in purpose of doing some twitter-text-conversion processing.

```
class NoteContentField(models.CharField):
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

    def to_python(self, value):
        value = super(NoteContentField, self).to_python(value)

        from ..utils import linkify
        return mark_safe(linkify(value))
```

However, this doesn't work.

When I save a Note object like this:

```
note = Note(author=request.use, 
            content=form.cleaned_data['content'])
note.save()
```

The conversed value is saved into the database, which is not what I wanna see.

What I'm trying to do is to save the raw content into the database, and only make the conversion when the content attribute is later accessed.

Would you please tell me what's wrong with this?

**Thanks to Pierre and Daniel.**

I have figured out what's wrong.

I thought the text-conversion code should be in either **to_python** or **get_db_prep_value**, and that's wrong.

I should override both of them, make to_python do the conversion and get_db_prep_value return the unconversed value:

```
from ..utils import linkify 
class NoteContentField(models.CharField):
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

    def to_python(self, value):
        self._raw_value = super(NoteContentField, self).to_python(value)
        return mark_safe(linkify(self._raw_value))

    def get_db_prep_value(self, value):
        return self._raw_value
```

I wonder if there is a better way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have only read half the docs. As Pierre-Jean noted above, and even linked you to the correct part of the document, you need to define the reverse function, which is `get_db_prep_value`.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean that I have to define both to_python and get_db_prep_value to make this work? If so, what should be in the get_db_prep_value method?

Comment: You are right, Daniel. It's a shame that I didn't read the manual with patience :(

Answer (score 1):

I think you should provide the reverse function to **to_python**.

Take a look at Django doc here : [Converting Python objects to query value](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#converting-python-objects-to-query-values)

Comment: This doesn't work either. *to_python* is for CONVERTING DATABASE VALUES TO PYTHON OBJECTS and that's what I want. However, the conversion happens twice, once when the field value is stored and once when the property is access.